# IOS Push Notification for day after without reopening the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

so I'm using OCPrayerTimes to get a set of strings in an

I use this code to get the array,

```
NSMutableArray *prayerTimes = [prayerTime prayerTimesDate:[NSDate date]
                                             latitude:3.1667
                                            longitude:101.7000
                                          andTimezone:[prayerTime getTimeZone]];
```

I then set notifications for each date in that array. Now my problem is that everyday those dates change so the user would have to re-open the app at midnight to get the new dates so the notifications would work.

Would I have to somehow run the viewdidload method at midnight everyday?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't automatically run your app every day, but you can schedule up to 64 local notifications, so you could calculate the prayer times for the next 12 days, and schedule notifications for all of them. This way the app wouldn't have to be opened every day.

Comment: Thanks. There is no method to get the prayer times for the next 12 days. How would I get the next 12 days ? run a for loop for a range a range of 12 days, would that be possible ?

Comment: You'd just have to pass different dates to the `prayerTimesDate:...` method (in a loop). Right now, you're always passing the current date (`[NSDate date]`).